# SwiftUI ForEach printing duplicate items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

In my application I am creating various arrays of Identifiable structs using my API response.  I am iterating over said array to build lists within the Content and Sidebar columns of my Navigation Split View.  If I print the array before my `ForEach` call, the array is normal.  When printing each item from within the `ForEach` (`let _ = print(item)`) the item prints twice.  However the item is only added to the List once.  Is this normal behavior?  It appears to be happening with all of my `ForEach` calls.  Visually the view looks correct, just want to be sure there isn’t any additional looping or view updated occurring.

Printing each item of array.  Resulting in duplicate prints.

```
//
//  TeamView.swift
//  myDashboard
//
//  Created by nl492k on 10/18/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TeamView: View {
    var user: loggedInUser
    var viewData = apiData()
    
// viewData is an instance of the apiData struct that includes 2 Arrays of identifieable structs ("gauges" & "trends") and a "team" struct that containts an array of idenfifiable structs "teamMembers"  viewData is a singular object that is updated by the completion handler of my API call.
    

//    struct apiData {
//        var gauges : Array<gaugeObj>
//        var trends : Array<trendObj>
//        var team : teamObj
//
//        init(gauges : Array<gaugeObj> = Array<gaugeObj>(), trends: Array<trendObj> = Array<trendObj>(), team: teamObj = teamObj()) {
//            self.gauges = gauges
//            self.trends = trends
//            self.team = team
//        }
//    }
    
    
    @Binding var uid_selection: String?
    var emulation_uid: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewData.team.attuid == "" {
            Label("Not Signed In", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.questionmark")
        }
        else {
            List(selection: $uid_selection){
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(value: viewData.team.superv) {
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(userImageUrl)\(viewData.team.attuid)")) { image in
                                image.resizable()
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                            } placeholder: {
                                ProgressView()
                            }
                            .frame(width:30, height: 35)
                            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                Text("\(viewData.team.fName) \(viewData.team.lName)")
                                Text("\(viewData.team.jobTitle)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .thin))
                            }
                        }
                        Label("", systemImage:"arrow.up.and.person.rectangle.portrait")
                    }
                Divider()
                //------ This prints the Array of identifiable structs, as expected, with no issues --------
                let _ = print(viewData.team.teamMembers)
                ForEach(viewData.team.teamMembers) { employee in
                    //----- This prints multiple times per employee in array ------.
                    let _ = print(employee)
                    NavigationLink(value: employee.attuid) {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(userImageUrl)\(employee.attuid)")) { image in
                            image.resizable()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                        .frame(width:30, height: 35)
                        VStack (alignment: .leading){
                            Text("\(employee.fName) \(employee.lName)")
                            Text("\(employee.jobTitle)")
                                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .thin))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color("ContentColumn"))
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    }
}

struct TeamView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TeamView(user: loggedInUser.shared,
                 viewData: apiData(gauges:gaugesTest,
                                   trends: trendsTest,
                                   team: teamTest),
                 uid_selection: .constant(loggedInUser.shared.attuid),
                 emulation_uid: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's potentially normal for views to be evaluated multiple times, but without seeing any code, it's impossible to diagnose your situation

Comment: Thanks, I will share code snippet. Due to the nature of the date, I may have to mock up some data. I can certainly share.

Comment: code added to question

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? This is not runnable as-is

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet, it looks like you're doing a print in the body of the `ForEach`, and seeing multiple prints per item.

Actually, this is completely normal behaviour because SwiftUI may render a view multiple times (which will cause your `print` statement to be called each time). There is no need to worry about such rerenders (unless you're debugging performance issues). SwiftUI's rendering heuristics isn't known to the public, and may sometimes choose to make multiple rendering passes even though no state variables have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by creating a class that warehouses an array that you wish to confirm if the View was created twice. So in your code, you would create a class outside the struct. Call it something like Model:

```
class ImagesAddedModel {
    var timesCounted = 0
}

struct TeamView: View {
  var imagesAddedModel = ImagesAddedModel()
...
}
```

Then you pull your view creator into a function that returns a view, in this case, an ASyncImage?. This function should reside in your TeamView Struct.

```
func makeImage(userImageUrl:String, employeeUID:UInt) -> ASyncImage? {
  if imagesAddedModel.timesCounted == 1 {
     imagesAddedModel.timesCounted = 0

     return AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(userImageUrl)\(employeeUID)")) { image in
                            image.resizable()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
    }
   imagesAddedModel.timesCounted += 1
   return nil
}
```

Finally, to update your ForEach with your new function.

```
ForEach(viewData.team.teamMembers) { employee in
                    //----- This prints multiple times per employee in array ------.
                    let _ = print(employee)
                    NavigationLink(value: employee.attuid) {
                       makeImage(userImageUrl:userImageUrl, employeeUID: employee.attuid)
                      ....
                    }
```